# karate: How to initial RemoteWebDriver in karate

Tags: karate

We are using docker in our CI process. I want to initiate 'RemoteWebDriver' in docker container for chrome. IS it possible doing this using karate framework?

Comment: As of now there is no built-in support, but you can try using the instructions here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#custom-target

Answer (score 1):

As of now there is no built-in support, but you can try using the instructions here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#custom-target

EDIT: this is supported in 0.9.5

Docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#webdriversession

Comment: I pulled your develop branch and build locally. I'm trying to run the UI feature demo-01.feature  but for some reason my getting runner exception as below. I'm pointing to mvn  <version>0.9.5.RC1</version>
*** runner exception stack trace ***
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 9: classpath:demo/abort/abort.feature
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)

Comment: When i try to run UI test in docker 

Feature: browser automation
Background:
 * configure driverTarget = { docker: 'justinribeiro/chrome-headless', showdriverTargetTargetLog: true}
   Scenario: try to login to github and then do a google search
    Given driverTarget 'https://github.com/login'
    And driverTarget.input('#login_field', 'hello')
    And driverTarget.input('#password', 'world')

I'm getting error as  no step-definition method match found for: driverTarget 'https://github.com/login'

Comment: Sorry for confusion actually I'm referring demo01.feature from demo under developer branch. I'm trying to set drivertarget using docker as per the example1 as * configure driverTarget = { docker: 'justinribeiro/chrome-headless', showDriverLog: true } . on windows 10 machine. I'm running Docker images justinribeiro/chrome-headless on my local docker instance. So problem is my test is failing opening browser at below step Given driver 'https://github.com/login' with error message as no step-definition method match found for: driverTarget 'https://github.com/login'

Comment: @PeterThomas  I hear you but your example on that link is chrome docker only.  How would you do IE11, for example?  Can you provide that info in your release notes?

Comment: @djangofan I would like to know what in the docs made you jump to the conclusion that karate is a drop-in replacement for “Grid” whatever that is. oh and this is open source, so please submit a PR :)

Comment: @PeterThomas  That isn't what I was saying:  I am saying that Karate should provide the option to communicate with a 'Selenium RemoteWebDriver' instance, similar to how Karate can currently talk to a local ChromeDriver.   Am I overlooking it?  Your karate-core documentation does not mention it anywhere.

Comment: @djangofan karate supports the w3c webdriver protocol so it should most likely support `RemoteWebDriver` already as-is but to be honest we have not had the time to try this and document it. maybe you can help ? hint: open source :)

Comment: Ok, I will try it.

Comment: Works now in 0.9.5 .  Thanks Peter!

Comment: @djangofan thanks for reminding me, I edited the answer with this info 